# Anyone has created c#.NET application to login into SAML 2.0 SSO configured salesforce org from Windows server 2012 with ADFS 2.0

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I have configured Salesforce (SAML 2.0 based) SSO with ADFS 2.0 in windows server 2012 R2. I want to create a c#.NET desktop application in which user should be automatically login into Salesforce org (via his domain credentials) and fetch some org's standard object metadata. 
I have googled for it and found 2 separate solutions:
1. Configure SSO in Salesforce with ADFS 2.0
2. .NET utility to login with domain (ADFS 2.0) credentials.

But I am not able to find combined solution of the same. If anybody has any idea on this or has implemented such setup (SAML based SSO in Salesforce with ADFS 2.0 & c#.NET utility to auto login to Salesforce org through domain credentials), then please share your knowledge.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 2.0 supports WS-Fed and SAML 2.0.

It sounds like you have federated ADFS and Salesforce.

So with an ASP MVC application (i.e. browser based) that uses e.g. WIF to connect to ADFS, you could connect because these protocols are all browser based.

For WS-Fed, this is called the passive profile.

You cannot use the passive profile for a desktop application as it has no browser support.

You need to use the active profile which is based on WCF and is supported by ADFS.